# GWT's class similar to AWT Desktop?

Tags: java, gwt, maven, gxt

Here is a little snippet of what I need to do:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
{
    final Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    try{
    desktop.open(new File(path));
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
     MessageBox.alert("Log View", "Error finding file", null);
    }
}
```

I need to open a file in the logged in users default desktop application for that file type. Maven is giving me issues on build saying it can't find java.io.File and java.awt.Desktop.

Kind of a 2 part question, first, does GWT have some sort of similar functionality to java.awt.Desktop and how do I fix the project so maven finds the io and awt files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the same effect as a `JButton` calling `Desktop` in HTML, you would provide an HTML button that links to a download of the file and ensure it has the correct content-type provided by the server.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically to the GWT part of the question.

Yes you can do this.  You would likely use either use a Grid, FlexTable, HTMLTable or event just HTML to display.  You would embed that widget into a panel, and display that panel on the root panel.

The trick will be to get the file data from the server to the client. You can do that using either GWT RPC, or some kind of REST server.  If you look at the default app that is produced when you start a GWT application, it will send back string data based on a string.  You can use that as a pattern to bring down your model object.  The default app uses GWT-RPC, and is pretty easy to follow.

The reason why I was vague on the type of widget is it will depend on how you want to present this data to your user.  You can use an HTML to just render HTML, but I would think you would want to use a better widget to truly render this data.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this with GWT.

Browsers typically have no access to the file system.  The best you can do is have the users install some plugin that gives you file access (will require a permission check) or have them upload a file to your server (your web app can download the file from there to inspect it).

Comment: I already have all of the file contents on the server, its just writing all of our internal logs to a single text file. But they want it to load in their environments default program, so once the file is created and I know its a text file how do I get it to open their default text editor?